# How can the approximation algorithm of one NP-complete problem be used to prove "the class P would be the same as the class NP"?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, p-vs-np

Recently, when I self-learnt Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th by Kenneth Rosen, I had some questions about some statements in it.

> Fur-
> thermore, if a polynomial worst-case time complexity algorithm were discovered for the traveling salesperson problem, many other difficult problems would also be solvable using polynomial
> worst-case time complexity algorithms (such as determining whether a proposition in n vari-
> ables is a tautology, discussed in Chapter 1). This follows from the theory of **NP-completeness**.
>
> A practical approach to the traveling salesperson problem when there are many vertices
> to visit is to use an **approximation algorithm**. ... That is, they may produce a Hamilton circuit with total weight W′ such that
> $W \le W′ \le cW$, where W is the total length of an exact solution and c is a constant ... If such an algorithm existed, this would show that the class P would be the **same**
> as the class NP, perhaps the most famous open question about the complexity of algorithms

I knew that NP can only be ["verifiable in polynomial time by a deterministic Turing machine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) while P can be **solved** in polynomial time by a deterministic Turing machine.

Then if we find one approximation algorithm for NP-complete which adds the NP-hard property for NP, then it only approximates **instead of solving** the problem. If it can solve, then based on NP-complete, all NP problems can be solved.

I also referred to one QA [answer](https://Proving%20an%20upper%20bound%20on%20the%20possible%20approximation%20is%20akin%20to%20P=NP) which states:

> Proving an **upper bound** on the possible approximation is akin to P=NP

But the answer seems to not answer the reasons behind the relation between the approximation algorithm and $P=NP$. This is weaker than the above finding both the lower bound $W$ and the upper bound $cW$.

Q:

How does the approximation algorithm for one NP-complete problem show that ["we can show the **existence** of an algorithm that solves any given instance of problem in NP in polynomial time"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50362/how-to-prove-p-neqnp#comment104185_50362), i.e. $P=NP$?

Comment: I suggest you search out lecture notes on approximation algorithms and hardness of approximation, which should cover this topic.  See also the first paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Hardness_of_approximation and [P-Complete Approximation Problems](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~teo/papers/JACM-PCom.pdf) (Sahni & Gonzalez, JACM v23n3 1976).

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd link solves with this problem although it is a bit beyond my ability currently. I will read it more detailedly when I learned targetedly about the complexity theory.